# npapi - javascript doesnt load the content of a plugin

Tags: firefox, plugins, npapi

I wrote a firefox plugin using C++ and used the `<EMBED>` to load it to html.

In javascript I got the embedded plugin by using document.getElementByID,
but when I tried to call a plugin function, the function was undefined. Moreover,
plugins constructors did not run while loading the page.

The same html file and plugin seems to work on some computers, while it doesnt work on others.

Does anyone have an idea what might by wrong?
How can I debug such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you reproduce it on your computer at first? If not, then try to figure out what systems, browsers, architecture, versions, they are using.

I recall, there are many GECKOSDK's, and each one has a specific version it works for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_sdk For example, different SDK's for Firefox 1.5-2.0, FireFox 3.0, Firefox 3.5, and Firefox 3.5

For different browers, make sure you are exposing the right DLL Exports, browsers can vary: http://git.webvm.net/?p=npsimple is a good starting point. You can use firebreath.googlecode.com too as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an object tag instead of `<embed>`.  In my experience,  doesn't seem to work as reliably.

If I had more information on how your plugin is structured (are you using XPCOM or npruntime?), I might be able to help more.